# How do I insert a table into a cell using word vba or a table within a table?

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I am new on VBA, I am creating a script to generate a report from a DB, I have been able to assemble a general draft of my report but I need to insert a table into an existing cell inside a word document, I have been surfing around but I am unable either to do a websearch with the correct terms in order to find some guidance on how to achieve this, If I am able to do it with my mouse I am sure I am able to do it through scripting, any resources that would help me in the right direction will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Yeah vote down people, as if you knew every answer in life, unbelievable, it is a genuine question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way, The secret is in the Range, to specify where do you want your nested table to be placed.

so, I am using Powershell so the syntax might vary a little

For creating the Table in the Document (assuming you already have a created document, if not you are missing that part which I am not going through since they already are several question/answer pairs on that subject).

> $TableX = $oDoc.Tables.Add($oDoc.Bookmarks("TableX").Range, 4, 3)

So TableX is our actual table, then we are telling word to use the helper method on the oDoc (Which is the name of our document object) to add a table, with a Bookmark named TableX (I will again not do a large explanation on this one, just for practical purposes, we name the Bookmark so we can reference to the table by Bookmark name later if we need to add data to it or manipulate it in any way we need) and at the same time we are calling to the method Range which is going to tell the Document Object where do we want the table to be placed, since we have not defined the range explicitly it will insert it in the next available line on the document,

Finally we specify how many rows and columns we would like in the table.

That is what we need for creating a table, now the tricky part, how do we insert a nested table, and moreover how do we specify where do we want this second table to be nested.

Well, with this:

> $oNestedTable = $oDoc.Tables.Add($TableX.Cell(4, 2).Range,7,3)

We name our nested table oNestedTable, then we are calling the same helper method we called before to add a new table to the document, but wait, look carefully at the differences, the range part of the command is pointing to a specific cell on in our first table, that is in the fourth row within the second cell, it is there where we are explicitly telling the document to insert a new table with 7 rows and 3 columns.

I hope this gives you some bare minimum guidance.

Regards

en